# How to rearrange characters javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, for-loop

Found some things like in Visual Basic but not Javascript and exactly what I'm trying to do. It's a tad bit different. I'm trying to figured out how to rearrange characters in a string, it's in a for loop as well in order to cut the string in half. Now I need to rearrange that.

First I have:

12345678910111213141516

then in the for loop

12345678

I'm trying fix it so now I get

72648531

But I have to do it in a way so people can't read the code and know that there's 8 characters at this point in the string without hard work and trouble. My for loop is also jumbled up and screwy so it can't be figured out. Something like this. I really cannot post the code though.

```
var con = "";
for (var i = complex math that equals 0; i < complex math to equal 8; i++) {
   var newStr = word[i]; // I need it to come out to the rearranged somewhere close by
   var con = con+""+newStr;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this? if you use plain javascript it will be always more or less easy to understand your code tricks. Consider real crypto for serious stuff

Comment: @luksch yeah it's crypto stuff but it's kind of like a little game. It's meant to be broken but not so easily.

Comment: You can't really do anything in javascript to make it hard to break, because anybody can open up the developer tools in his/her browser and see everythig you do. For example the results of your complex maths. Or your character jumbling logic.

Comment: it's all in there it just has to be reversed engineered. And there are a list of all of the words generated. I've spent a lot of time writing up everything I just cannot release the code because I don't want people to have it yet. Basically: for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) and var word = "123456789abcdefg";

Answer (score 0):

Two commonly used techniques come to mind:

1. A common approach to things is by doing some XOR calculations: Look at this unrelated examples:

   - http://www.javascriptsource.com/passwords/xor-encryption4.html
   - [Extracting information from page with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495764/extracting-information-from-page-with-jsoup/21497490#21497490)
2. You can use tools like http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx to make it harder for people to figure your code.